# Form Validation phone number pattern html5

Tags: html, forms, validation, tel

I've searched far and wide but cannot seem to find the answer I need.

As we all know phone numbers around the world vary, my client's online form needs people to enter their phone number, but in a format of having the + symbol in the front. I know I can create a specific pattern to do this, but how do I create a pattern that has the + symbol at the front with a variable quantity of number after the symbol?

I'm happy to return a number like +60 1234567891.

I've also seen forms whereby the country code is selectable as part of the element... that would be good, but as long as I can solve my orginal issue I'll be happy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at the below script that can help you to validate phone number in html5 14 is the number of elements that can you enter by keyboard it accepts +sign with space and number.

```
<input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="[+ 0-9]{14}" required >
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is using JS, I am looking more towards the HTML5 whereby I use the code required patern="blah blah" Title="Please use correct format" etc

Comment: <input name="phone" type="text" pattern="/[^0-9+]/g"> try this

Comment: ^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([1-9][0-9]{9})$ also work with + sign with all the country

Comment: <input type="tel" pattern="^[0-9+]$" >

Comment: None of the above worked... I can put just 2 numbers in and it accepts it, didn't even put the + symbol and it syill accepts it.

Comment: <input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{13}" required >
here + sign is compulsory if it show red border then you are wrong otherwise you are right.it accepts total 14 characters with plus sign and numbers.

Comment: That works, but forces 14 characters, I need a variable not fixed to a specific number of characters, some number may have 12, some may have 15.

Comment: I have worked it out, I used
 [+]{1}[0-9]{11,14}
Thank you for your help sunil :)

Comment: @sunil the second regex which i upvoted worked for me like a charm, thanks :D